# Haxe - float null confusion

Tags: null, haxe

Here is sample of my code in Haxe

```
public function new(CminSpeed:Null<Float>,CmaxSpeed:Null<Float>)
{
    if (CminSpeed == null)
    {
        CminSpeed = 0.1;
    }
    if (CmaxSpeed == null)
    {
        CmaxSpeed = 3;
    }

    minSpeed = CminSpeed;
    maxSpeed = CmaxSpeed;
}
```

Im trying to set default value to variable in constructor while parameters are null. But it never jump into condition block, even while values are null. So in result variables `minSpeed` and `maxSpeed` are always null when it passes null.

Im begginer in haxe, i really dont understand how nullable objects work, documentation couldnt help me with this.

Comment: Thanks much it helped ! Sometimes Haxe drives me angry.

Comment: My answer should be unaccepted, so that I can delete it and then you can then accept @MarkKnol's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your input values are incorrect. I created a simple example, check it out:
http://try.haxe.org/#54200
This looks like expected results to me. You are basically doing it correct.

The idea of `Null<T>` is to never use `if (bla==0)` (because that really sucks) but to use `if (bla==null)` (nullable). That should work, otherwise it is a bug.

btw. try.haxe.org is a nice tool to check such functionality. You can even see the output-source of JavaScript-target. In swf-target (from what I know) an object is wrapped around the float, so you should handle it with care if performance is expected.

Also, check out this if you haven't seen it yet: http://haxe.org/manual/types-nullability.html